# Trouble installing scipy via pyCharm windows 8 - no lapack / blas resources found

Tags: python, pycharm, lapack, blas

I'm currently having trouble installing scipy via PyCharm's package manager. I have installed numpy successfully and do have the Microsoft Visual Studio C/C++ compiler in the System Variables.

However, when it's time to install scipy in PyCharm, the following error occurs:

*Executed Command: pip install scipy*

*Error occured: numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found*

I have seen other resources on installing blas / lapack on windows, but I'm unsure if it will work with PyCharm's installations.

If anybody has the solution / resources to redirect me to, please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you're using the python.org version(s) of Python, the easiest way to install packages is to first check if they are in Christoph Gohlke's [Python Extension Packages for Windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) repository. There are pre-compiled packages for both [`numpy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and [`scipy`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy), along with many many others. You'll need to install `numpy` from there, as it is statically-linked to Intel's MKL, and is a necessary dependency for many of the other packages there, including `scipy`.

Comment: This worked for me. Once I'd downloaded the pre-compiled whl files, I ran `pip install C:\path\to\numpy-1.9.2+mkl-cp27-none-win32.whl` and the same for scipy

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm uses **pip** utility so if any error occurs during package installation it means that if you try   **pip install < package >**  in the command line you will get the same error.

So in your case the best way is to install pre-compiled package from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ for your interpreter in the command line and after that restart PyCharm. Also you can check that now the package is in a package list for your interpreter: Settings| Project| Project interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to install Python packages for science, math, engineering, data analysis - is using [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads).

It's a Python distribution, that comes with the most popular packages (see the list of packages [here](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs.html)).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and downloading Anaconda, and switching the project interpreter in PyCharm to \Anaconda3\python.exe helped solve this.

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Install python packages using Anaconda and use interpreter as anaconda/python.exe
when creating new python projects.

It worked well for me without giving above errors.

[Refer this:create a project using PyCharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28Gk9.png)