# not able to install scikit-learn on pycharm on windows

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pycharm

I am trying to install scikit learn on Pycharm but it always shows an error:

*" numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found. "*

Also, pycharm is not able to recognize pre-installed libraries(basically I installed some libraries  eg. numpy scikit learn using pip in cmd)

it is not able to install other libraries such as matplotlib. 
The only library it installed is **numpy, pandas.**

**the project interpreter is correct, but still, i am getting an error while installing these libs.**

Comment: I think this question is already answered in previous post at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29883791/10744959.

Comment: Use Anaconda and create a new conda environment to install scikit-learn, numpy, scipy etc. This is by far the easiest approach. If anything is missing in conda then use pip install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PyCharm go to File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter. Click on the + sign on the right hand side of the window. Type the name of the library you want to install and PyCharm will add it for you.

When PyCharm is unable to make that installation, it usually has to do with your virtual environment not being set up correctly.

Comment: I just noticed your question said you were using pip. You will need to make sure the pip executable matches the version of python you are using for your project. Installation of new libraries will fail if the pip/python version aren't correct.