# How to fix large pip error when install scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I received this error, when tried to install scikit-learn:

```
C:\Users\mjanota\Downloads\mtswm2-master> pip install -U scikit-learn
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.23.2.tar.gz (7.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\mjanota\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lenx41py\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1'
       cwd: None
  Complete output (222 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation != "CPython"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting Cython>=0.28.5
    Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)
  Processing c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\88\21\07\12b17bd52e2030a53d9757e9d65610e73d4075ee2d7c456d70\numpy-1.17.3-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting scipy>=0.19.1
    Using cached scipy-1.5.3.tar.gz (25.2 MB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
    Getting requirements to build wheel: started
    Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing wheel metadata: started
      Preparing wheel metadata: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\mjanota\AppData\Local\Temp\tmposc00obu'
           cwd: C:\Users\mjanota\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xve6o74g\scipy
      Complete output (195 lines):
      setup.py:460: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('dist_info --egg-base C:\Users\mjanota\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-9bx10ir1'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        warnings.warn("Unrecognized setuptools command ('{}'), proceeding with "
      Running from SciPy source directory.
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\mjanota\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mjanota\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_lapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\mjanota\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mjanota\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      openblas_clapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\mjanota\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mjanota\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      flame_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\mjanota\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mjanota\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_3_10_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      atlas_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      accelerate_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      lapack_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\mjanota\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\mjanota\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\mjanota\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wuqehbxd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      C:\Users\mjanota\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wuqehbxd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
        NOT AVAILABLE
  
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
          main()
        File "c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 133, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\mjanota\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wuqehbxd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 161, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\mjanota\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wuqehbxd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 253, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\mjanota\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wuqehbxd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 583, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "setup.py", line 579, in setup_package
          setup(**metadata)
        File "C:\Users\mjanota\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wuqehbxd\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 137, in setup
          config = configuration()
        File "setup.py", line 477, in configuration
          raise NotFoundError(msg)
      numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: No lapack/blas resources found.
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\mjanota\AppData\Local\Temp\tmposc00obu' Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\mjanota\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip' install
--ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\mjanota\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-lenx41py\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation == '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation != '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I tried to use: `pip install --exists-action=i scikit-learn` with exactly the same output.

Ealier I had similar problem with installing matplotlib, but in that case, the computer restart was a solution.

I have python version 3.9 installed (and some of the previous ones) on Windows 10 operating system, and I'm using Visual Studio Code with powershell terminal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble installing scipy via pyCharm windows 8 - no lapack / blas resources found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883690/trouble-installing-scipy-via-pycharm-windows-8-no-lapack-blas-resources-foun)

Comment: Unfortunetely not :(  Exactly the same output when downloading a package and install via pip

Comment: Several days have passed, and it just worked (probably after pip update)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue in Python 3.9. Please downgrade your Python version to complete the installation successfully.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

install it from github master solve the issue for me

```
pip install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also running into the same issue while installing Pycaret because it was looking for scikit learn dependency and tries to match python version upto 3.8

I suggest to create a virtual environment with python 3.8 and then try to install.

Worked for me.

(I created virtual environment in Pycharm)